# Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r

Trying to plot this and I'm having some trouble with the output...
When I enter:

```
glmerviab <- glmer(survivorship ~ Temp + Days + (1|ID), family = binomial, GLMdata)
summary(glmerviab)
x<- seq(0, 365, 0.1)
y <- predict(glmerviab, list(Days = x), type = "response")

plot(x = GLMdata$Days, y = GLMdata$survivorship, main = "Probit Model of survivorship", xlab = 
"Days", ylab = "survivorship", pch = 20, ylim = c(-0.4, 1.4), cex.main = 0.85)

lines(x, y)
```

I get:

```
> y <- predict(glmerviab, list(Days = x), type = "response")
Error in rep(0, nobs) : invalid 'times' argument
```

I do get a plot with points, but no lines.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you intend for x to be a vector of [0, 1, 2, ...365], or to be [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 365.0]?

Comment: Not sure how the title is related to the content. Also perhaps a [mcve] would help?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the `newdata=` argument as a data frame, not a list. I can reproduce your error as follows:

```r
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
predict(fm1, list(Days = 1:10))
```

> Error in rep(0, nobs) : invalid 'times' argument

However, this only gets me a little bit farther:

```r
predict(fm1, data.frame(Days = 1:10))
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Subject' not found

In order to do predictions you either need to specify which levels of the grouping variable you want to predict for, *or* use `re.form` to specify that you want to do prediction at the population level:

```r
predict(fm1, data.frame(Days = 1:10), re.form = NA)
##       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
## 261.8724 272.3397 282.8070 293.2742 303.7415 314.2088 324.6761 335.1434 
##        9       10 
## 345.6107 356.0780
```